# What's an alternative to "Take the leap"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

In the context of making or executing upon a big decision: What is a simple phrase that is similar to "Take the leap" or "Go for it"?

Comment: plunge in, seize the day,  get off you butt,  get started?

Comment: Are you planning to use this phrase in a formal or casual setting?

Comment: Take the plunge. // You need to say why you don't want "Take the leap" or "Go for it."  And provide a sample sentence or situation.

Comment: Semi-formal setting

Answer (score 1):

You **take the bull by the horns**, when you make a challenging or difficult decision. Metaphorically, this is not something that can be done halfway.

> take the bull by the horns Fig. to confront a problem head-on and deal
>    with it openly.
>
> **It's time to take the bull by the horns and get this job done.**
>
> > McGraw-Hill Dictionary of merican Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002

In addition, the advertising slogan for Nike always come to mind in response to a situation where there's indecision or doubt:  **Just do it!**

Answer (score 1):

**carpe diem**

It is a catchy little Latin phrase that means "seize the day."

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/carpe-diem

Comment: Are you sure that's the definition you wanted to link to?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: Guess not. Good catch. Thank you.