# Is it possible to say: "He swung at something complicated"?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

In my language, this phrase will mean that some person is trying to do some difficult thing, which at this moment is either at the limit of his capabilities or even higher.

So, is it possible to say in this way? Will native English speakers understand me or will this phrase sound strange?

In russian it sounds like: "Замахнуться на что-то сложное", "Я замахнулся на эту сложную задачу, но сомневаюсь, что смогу с ней справиться".

Comment: In English, if  you swing at something, that image is taken from cricket or baseball. But swinging does not mean *you actually hit the ball*. Maybe "took a swing at x" meaning attempted to do x.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's an alternative to "Take the leap"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386826/whats-an-alternative-to-take-the-leap) The meaning of 'take a swing at' is given in many dictionaries, eg [the Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+swing+at).

Comment: The cited use of ***something*** as an "intensifier" is *extremely* casual (and it's primarily BrE rather than AmE, I suspect). You'll find it in contexts like *"It stinks **something awful**!", "They beat him up **something terrible**!", "He swung at me [**something fierce**!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hit+me+something+fierce%22)"*

Comment: You say the person "is trying" but also use the past tense "swung". If you swung at something it means you tried in the past, not that you're currently trying.

Comment: I've *never* encountered this usage with ***complicated***, and I'm not convinced it could ever be "idiomatic". But it's certainly not *syntactically valid* according to strict grammar.

Comment: Yes, that's not syntactically valid, I got it. 
Sorry for my bad English. Trying to use my own skills and translator to answer to your comments and answers)
Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Lambie, can you formalize your comment with an answer?

Comment: As mentioned below, [swing for the fences](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swing-for-the-fences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, if you swing at something, that image is taken from cricket or baseball.

But swinging does not mean you actually hit the ball. Maybe "took a swing at x" meaning attempted to do x.

In a conversation, one can imagine this:

John: Well, he really made a mess of trying to get that difficult client.
Mario: Yeah, it was very difficult. He took a swing at a complicated problem. And missed.

Comment: For baseball, **swing for the fences** means try for a distant goal.

Comment: @YosefBaskin In baseball, one wants to clear the fence, not hit it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention hitting the fences.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Perhaps not but it is included in "swing for the fence".

Comment: You may be right.

Answer (score 1):

You might express this with the English idiom ***to take the bull by the horns***, which means

> to do something difficult in a brave and determined way
> to deal with a difficult situation in a very direct way:
>
> > ***I took the bull by the horns*** and confronted him about his mistreatment of the workers. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-the-bull-by-the-horns))

Comment: This phrase is close in meaning to the one above, but it is not similar in emotional coloring. "Taking the bull by the horns" is a very strong statement with the strongest intention to do what I need to do. And the above-mentioned phrase has a much softer coloring. I would even say that with some uncertainty that you will be able to do what you have planned.
I can describe the differences like this: "I swung at something complicated, and trying to do this with all my might, but..." And someone will say to me, "Stop doubting, just take the bull by the horns."

Comment: What is the actual Russian idiom? Translated literally into English doesn't pinpoint the meaning you are after.

Comment: In russian: "Замахнуться на что-то сложное", "я замахнулся(past tense) на эту задачу, но сомневаюсь, что смогу выполнить ее".
I translated it verbatim and got: "I swing at something difficult".
Maybe, @lambie was right and It may better to say: "To took a swing at something difficult"?

Comment: Maybe one of these:
1) have a crack/shot at something difficult/complicated;
2) to try one's hand at something difficult;
3)  attempt smth/to do smth(but It's too straightforward);

Comment: Yes, the idiom is "take a swing at".

Answer (score 0):

● Literal Interpretation: One might visualize a person swinging their arm in an attempt to physically hit or interact with something complex, perhaps in a metaphorical sense. This could imply a struggle or effort to deal with a difficult physical object or situation.
● Metaphorical Interpretation: This phrase could be understood figuratively, suggesting that "he" is trying to handle or understand a complex idea, situation, or problem. It could convey the idea of someone grappling with a challenging task or concept, putting in effort to make sense of it.
● Emotional Interpretation: Another perception could be that "he" is emotionally struggling with something complicated. This could imply feelings of confusion, frustration, or uncertainty about a difficult situation or decision.
● Perception of Difficulty: The phrase could also suggest that the thing "he" is dealing with is inherently complex or challenging. It might imply that the task or situation is not easily understood or resolved.
● Sense of Action: Additionally, the word "swung" can imply a decisive or forceful action. This could suggest that "he" is actively trying to address or confront the complexity, showing determination or initiative.
Overall, the phrase is open to interpretation and can evoke different perceptions based on the individual's understanding and context interpretation of "he swung at something complicated" can be understood based on the meanings of the individual words and how they are commonly used.

SEE BELOW:
● "Swung": This word implies a physical action, often associated with trying to hit or interact with something.
● "Complicated": This word suggests something that is intricate, difficult, or not easily understood.
When these words are combined in the phrase, it can be inferred that "he" is taking a physical action (swinging) toward something that is complex or difficult to deal with (complicated). This can be seen as a metaphor for grappling with a challenging situation, concept, or problem.

This interpretation aligns with common usage and understanding of these words, which is why the phrase is likely to be understood in this way by most English speakers. I am newbie here. This is a cool opportunity, just to entangle with literacy and good people. ❤️

Comment: What is your source?  Please include citations and see the [help] on how to answer and [edit].